# Heroku Slug Size exceed Limits More than 300m

Tags: java, spring, git, heroku

My heroku slug size is 389mb, so push is rejected. Now the Point is, if i deploy my same application on new domain (by using heroku create again), the slug size, i am seeing is just 200mb.. Why its different? Then I have tried this approach:

Approach 1: by deleting `.git` folder from my project directory, then again `git init`. and then deploying again on same heroku app.. It didn't make any differences!

Approach 2: By declaring `.slugignore` file in root of project folder. But its too not making any diff!

Approach 3: as per this site, https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo

I have reset my repo like this,

```
heroku repo:reset -a appname
```

But, nothing happened!! What to do now? Can u guide me? Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Heroku suggests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size):

- Inspect your slug with `heroku run bash` and by using commands such as `ls` and `du`
- Move large assets like PDFs or audio files to asset storage
- Remove unneeded dependencies and exclude unnecessary files via `.slugignore`

Comment: I don't have any pdf or psd docs, I have tried .slugignore file, but there were no changes made by adding it. finally i have rebuilt my repo by heroku Repo plugin.. Thanx.

Comment: Just FYI; this answer is here now because I merged the question it was originally posted to to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was able to find the solution. Here is what i have done:

I have downloed Heroku Repo plugin from this site :https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo just by this line:

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git
```

then I have just rebuilt my app by this command:

```
heroku repo:rebuild -a appname
```

This will empty the remote repository and push the repository up again, effectively triggering an app rebuild. and I got whole working app with original downsized (207mb) again. that's it.

Comment: `repo:rebuild` is not a listed command anymore, now a `repo:reset` will at least clear the heroku repo again and the next build i guess will work again